# C++ Crash Reporting in cocos2dx using hockeyapp

Tags: java, c++, macos, debugging, crash-reports

i'm working with cocos2dx and integrated hockeyapp in it to implement a feature of crash reporting. But i found that i can only send crashes generated in java through android hockeyApp. As cocos2dx involves c++ as well so Crashes occurred in c++ will not be entertained by hockeyApp lib. Can anyone guide me about how can i achieve this feature in c++ ?

Regards,
Qaiser Butt

Comment: why java meaning? BTW i'm working with android hockeyApp written in java. There is a possible way to call up java methods by c++ through JNI.

Comment: From what i found here you can catch native crashes using hockey app, did you implement the C++ crash handling?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately hockey app does not support C++, [this](http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/33390-hockeyapp-integration-for-chtmljs-windows-app) made me very sad.

Hockey app + JNI (NDK)
[Here](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android-other-platforms/hockeyapp-for-android-ndk-early-access)

However, it may be possible to translate the dumps generated from breakpad or similar to a format that fits hockey app as done [here](https://keithjohnston.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/windows-crash-reporting-with-hockeyapp/)